# Destroy and instantiate player prefab

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject, prefabs

I am new to game development.
I am trying to change the player prefab every X seconds.
For that, I am destroying the previously spawned prefab and instantiating a new prefab.
But I don't know how to DESTROY THE PREFAB (not the empty game object on which the script is attached)

This is my code :

```
[SerializeField]
public GameObject[] objectToSpawn;

public float ChangeInterval = 5;
public float timer;


private void Update()
{
    int Rand = Random.Range(0, objectToSpawn.Length);
    GameObject spawnPrefab = objectToSpawn[Rand];

    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer >= ChangeInterval)
    {
        
        Instantiate(spawnPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        timer -= ChangeInterval;
       }
    Destroy(gameobject);
    


}
```

Please tell me how can I destroy the prefab.
Also is this the correct approach for it??
Thank You.

Comment: You destroy right away the current one. If it should be destroyed after X time, you should place the destroy in the timer loop as well

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not to destroy the prefab (the asset in your file system that tells you what properties this object should have), but to destroy the spawned *instance* of that prefab - the new copy of it that you've created in your scene.

`Instantiate()` returns a reference to this instance, so save it in a variable so you know what object to destroy later.

You can also do this without an `Update()` method or `timer` variable, like so:

```cs
// Use a coroutine instead of ticking Update every frame.
IEnumerator Start() {
    // Store the interval in seconds between prefab changes.
    var delay = new WaitForSeconds(ChangeInterval);

    // Repeat forever.    
    while (true) {
        // Select a prefab to spawn only when it's time to spawn one.
        int prefabIndex = Random.Range(0, objectToSpawn.Length);
        var prefab = objectToSpawn[Rand];

        // Spawn that prefab and capture a reference to this new copy.
        var instance = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        // Return control to the main game loop until it's time to spawn again.
        // (This prevents the infinite loop from making the game hang).
        yield return delay;

        // Delete the last instance we spawned.
        Destroy(instance);

        // Resume from the top of the loop.
    }
}
```